# How to style jquery widgets as they are added to the window via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I have done this before, but at the moment it is slipping my mind.

How would I go about styling jQuery widgets as they are added to the window? For example...

```
<html>
<div id="somediv"></div>
<script>
    $("#button").button();
    $("somediv").html("<input id='button'>");
</script>
```

The output should contain a jQuery button object in somediv after load, but does not, because #button did not exist at the time the $("#button") selector was called.  Obviously I could just switch the two lines in the script in this example, but in reality I'm adding the buttons dynamically via AJAX.  I know that there is some way to add a listener to the window via jQuery to style the widgets, because I've done it before, I've just forgotten how and can't find it via a search now.

EDIT: I understand how to make the code work if I style the button after it is added.  The whole point is to have the object declaration BEFORE the button exists, and then automatically applied to the button after it is added via AJAX.  I have done this before, I just forget how.

Comment: Sorry, you can't without using methods that are either deprecated or supported in only a select few browsers. You'll have to initialize the widgets after they have been added. The only other option is using a setInterval that periodically checks for new elements, however that's very inefficient.

Comment: This seems to be right, though I would swear to you that I've done it before.

Comment: It is possible with widgets that act upon an event (such as datepicker or autocomplete.) Buttons can't be done that way because they need to be styled immediately.

Comment: If you're gonna use ajax I think it would be better to provide the code instead of what your <script></script> and then explain that you're gonna use ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add a global listener, that will react to a button click, on a button that may not exist, you can write:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){
    // Click logic here
});
```

If you actually need to STYLE it, then you have to call a function to do that after an ajax call

But you can style in memory elements:

Say that you receive this: `"<button id="button"></button>"` from an Ajax call.

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( newHtml ) {
  var $newHtml = $(newHtml); // Convert the string to a jquery object. 
  // $newHtml - This will be in memory and NOT in the DOM

  // Then you can style it and add classes as you like
  $newHtml.css('color', 'red');
  $newHtml.addClass('btn btn-danger');
  // And finally append it somewhere
  $('#somediv').append($newHtml);
});
```

Where the resulting button will look like:

```
 <button id="button" style="color: red;" class="btn btn-danger"></button>
```

Comment: I think maybe adding the listener in this manner is what I remember doing in the past, and I'm just remembering it as styling.

Comment: @Morslamina I used to use this often for dynamic content.

Comment: @Morslamina I updated my answer, this might be what you were looking for

Comment: Still not quite what I was looking for, but this is the most useful answer, so I will accept it.

Comment: Doesn't make more sense just to do that in the done function instead of getting a string from the server? That's why I said you should provide the code. To my understanding as I said in my answer you should be adding the button(s) and styling them in the .done

Comment: @mitomed That is kind of what it does in the code, isn't it?

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen, sure. I'm not criticising your answer. I'm just pointing Morslamina should have clarified what button(s) wanted providing the actual code. As for the example he gave us getting a string from the server is overkilling in my opinion as everything can be cleanly done in the .done J

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
$("#somediv").html("<input   id='button' style='padding:5px;' />");
```

or you can add custom classes to it which can be styled easily

```
$("#somediv").html("<input type='button' id='button' class='myclass' />");
```

**EDIT**

you can create button using

```
$('body').append($('<input/>',{type:button, value:"somevalue", "class":"someclass"});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, or why this would work?

Comment: @PranavCBalan I have edited it. Still having error?

Comment: I think you both misunderstand my question.

Comment: I think he understands it completely. You want to add an element and have it automagically have the button widget applied. that isnt possible, this answer is an alternative.

Comment: @Morslamina I have edited the answer. Is that you want?

Comment: Anoop - it isn't what I want, but it seems like Kevin is right.  What I want does not exist, though I would swear to you that I have done it before.

Answer (score 0):

One option is applying the style in the success function:

```
 $.ajax({
     //...do your call
 })
 .done(function(){
     $("somediv").html("<input id='button'>")
     //Now you can apply your class/style (even using the JQuery css method if you'd want)
 });
```

Don't know if it's something you would consider